# IIS 7 multiple site bindings: Browser opens to wrong place

Tags: asp.net, binding, iis-7, a-records, multiple-sites

I have a 2008 R2 IIS server hosting two sites.  One site works fine when browsing to it. It defaults to wwwroot.  Anyone browsing to www.example.com or example.com goes to the correct page for this site. Everything works.

The second site is supposed to default to the subfolder wwwroot\update where an asp.net application resides.  Anyone browsing to update.example.com should go to this site.  The binding doesn't work.  It uses the default documents and config files in wwwroot instead of the ones under wwwroot\update. Why?

I have verified site 1 points to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and the other points to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\update.  It doesn't make any sense that the second site would even look at wwwroot as something that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to set up a new site in IIS rather than adding `update.example.com` to the bindings. This would allow you to point the update.example.com binding to a separate directory on your server.

Comment: That's what I did, and as I explain above, the second site doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same port and IP address bound to the both sites? If so, you should add a host header to each site. www.example.com to the first and update.example.com to the second.  This will only work if they are http sites.